# Simple Python Converter Error

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to learn functions and wanted to make a simple kilograms to pounds, or vise versa. Whenever I run my code, it outputs "None" and I don't understand why.

```
def convert(amount, measurement):
    if measurement == "kilograms":
        float(amount) * 2.2
    if measurement == "pounds":
        float(amount) / 2.2

amount_measure = raw_input("How many are you converting?")
amount_measurement = raw_input("What are you converting?")

if amount_measurement == 'kilograms':
    print "You have %r pounds." % convert(amount_measure, amount_measurement)

if amount_measurement == 'pounds':
    print "You have %r kilograms." % convert(amount_measure, amount_measurement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the values. Use the return command. Something like this

```
return float(amount) * 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(amount, measurement):
    if measurement == "kilograms":
        return float(amount) * 2.2
    if measurement == "pounds":
        return float(amount) / 2.2

amount_measure = raw_input("How many are you converting?")
amount_measurement = raw_input("What are you converting?")

if amount_measurement == 'kilograms':
    print "You have %r pounds." % convert(amount_measure, amount_measurement)

if amount_measurement == 'pounds':
    print "You have %r kilograms." % convert(amount_measure, amount_measurement)
```